# DFT explanation for a given signal providing samples per second and total samples

Tags: dft

I'm new to the topic of DFT and I need to understand the following question in detail because I'm a bit confused and I need to solve the requirements needed using any programming language

[image]

so taking DFT discrete function into consideration. is the **n** in our function x(m) the sampling rate which is equal to 20? also is **N** the total number of samples which is 100?

[image]

[image]
also how to represent the signal x(t) to compute the DFT? and how to apply the comparison on the three cases.
I know that in x(t) if we represented it as a relation between a frequency and amplitude, it would be a spike depending on the given value of t which should be either 0 or above and 0 otherwise. if there is any correction to what I understand, I would be really thankful.

Comment: Look at (2) and (3) -- what do you think the prof meant with (3)?  "how to represent the signal x(t) to compute the DFT"  You are given $x(t)$, and you are given the sampling rate.  What's missing, and how do you compute it?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question, $n$ is not the sampling rate that is equal to 20, but $N$ is the total number of samples equal to 100. $n$ is a counting index that goes through each of those samples in turn, starting at index 0 and ending at 99. This puts the time domain in units of "samples" rather than units of "seconds".

So to represent $x[n]$ instead of $x(t)$, realize that the sampling rate will convert units of $t$ to units on $n$: since the sampling rate is 20 samples per second, consider then what would $t$ be for each sample? What is the duration of each sample in time? From this you can then determine $x[n]$ from $x(t)$ for each sample and then use the formula directly as written.

Comment: thank you so much for your help.